# Problems in setting up qBittorrent with web UI

Tags: raspbian, ssh, headless, raspberry-pi-os

I am using RPi 4 Rev B in headless mode(without display, using ssh to connect to the machine).

I want to run qBittorrent on startup on this machine and control it with other machine using web UI.

Currently, I am able to run qBittorrent manually using "ssh -X". I have enabled Web UI option in the preference. I have also checked "Start qBittorrent minimized" option in Preferences.

Now, to achieve my goal, I am trying to qBittorrent as a service on startup.

I have added the service file(/etc/systemd/system/qbittorrent.service):

```
[Unit]
Description=qBittorrent client
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/qbittorrent
#Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

But, the service is failing to start. Failure logs:

```
x@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo service qbittorrent status
● qbittorrent.service - qBittorrent client
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/qbittorrent.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2021-10-15 08:17:24 BST; 6min ago
  Process: 457 ExecStart=/usr/bin/qbittorrent (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 457 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Oct 15 08:17:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started qBittorrent client.
Oct 15 08:17:24 raspberrypi qbittorrent[457]: qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display
Oct 15 08:17:24 raspberrypi qbittorrent[457]: Could not connect to any X display.
Oct 15 08:17:24 raspberrypi systemd[1]: qbittorrent.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 15 08:17:24 raspberrypi systemd[1]: qbittorrent.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot start a graphical program as a service the same way regular services are started: it will have no display to connect to, and if you somehow provide a display (by connecting to an X server during startup and setting the `DISPLAY` variable) it will likely complain there is no user session.

I suggest you install a torrent client with no GUI, e.g. `transmission-cli`, which already comes with a service (`tramsimssion-daemon`).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just wanted to add one more thing. qBittorrent can also be used without GUI by running `qbittorrent-nox`. I found out it from their official wiki.
For more details: https://github.com/qbittorrent/qBittorrent/wiki/Running-qBittorrent-without-X-server-(WebUI-only,-systemd-service-set-up,-Ubuntu-15.04-or-newer)

Comment: @rohit15079 That's good to know, too bad `qbittorrent-nox` doesn't seem to include a systemd service like `transmission-daemon` does. If you got `qbittorrent-nox` working, feel free to post it as an answer!